# Get last row from a query generated table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello everyone I have wrote a query which will give me employee in and out time for a range of time, as my tables have many in and out time I wanted to get only last in or out time based on timestamp here is query for this

```
select
fullname,direction,to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy  hh12:mi:ss PM') as Time,
gate,lane,employment.employeeid,NATIONALID,departmentname,designation.designationname
from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa
join eofficeuat.employee on entrylog_cpa.hrrecordid=employee.hrrecordid
join eofficeuat.employment on employee.hrrecordid=employment.hrrecordid
join eofficeuat.designation on employment.designationid=designation.designationid
join eofficeuat.department on employment.departmentid=department.departmentid
where department.departmentname = 'SECURITY'
and tstamp >= 1568764800 and tstamp < (select (sysdate - date '1970-01-01') * 86400000 from dual)
/*and tstamp in (select max(tstamp) from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa)*/
/*and rownum >= (select count(tstamp) from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa)*/
and fullname='A.K.M.TOWHID SARKER'
order by fullname asc;
```

this query give this result

```
 full name            direction   time
 ---------            ---------   ----
 A.K.M.TOWHID SARKER  out         18-09-2019  01:41:35 PM
 A.K.M.TOWHID SARKER  out         18-09-2019  01:29:08 PM
```

but I only want last row from this result. can you please help how can i do this?

Comment: how do you define a last row?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle 19c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your query and use `ROW_NUM()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    -- your query with an ORDER BY clause
) x WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Please note that this selects the first row in the resultset. If you want the last row, you would need to change your `ORDER BY` clause to sort the opposite way in the first place.

If you are running Oracle 12c or higher, you don't need to wrap the query, you can use a `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` clause.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ...
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Where ROWNUM=1 only showing first row from this result, I wanted get last row

Comment: @mdkamrul: yes, see the note in my answer. you just need to reverse the sorting order, so `order by fullname desc` instead of `order by fullname asc`.

Comment: Note: since you are using 19c, you could use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` instead of `ROWNUM` (still sorting by *descending* name)

Comment: when i run Fetch first row only then I am getting the error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 1"